# String compatibility error, attempt to index a nil value

Tags: lua, gideros

I am using Gideros and getting this error:

```
    main.lua:47: attempt to index a nil value
stack traceback:
    main.lua:47: in function 'func'
    [string "compatibility.lua"]:36: in function <[string "compatibility.lua"]:35>
```

I have this piece of code and as soon as the text is displayed, it gives me the above mentioned error:How can I fix this?

```
function onEnter()
    function youLoose()
    local font2 = TTFont.new("billo.ttf", 20, "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    LooserText = TextField.new(font2, "You Loose   , Try AGAIN?")
    LooserText:setPosition(100, 100)
    stage:addChild(LooserText)
    Timer = Timer.delayedCall(1000, removing)
    end --line 36
   end   
    function removing()
    LooserText:getParent():removeChild(LooserText)  --line 47
    end
```

Comment: That's not the full error message, only the location. What is the error message?

Comment: Also you "lose" a game/race and something is "loose" when it doesn't fit well. Also you probably don't want to overwrite `Timer` like that assuming the returned value from that call is not the `Timer` module and that `Timer` is a module and not an instance of a timer.

Comment: need to know what is line 32 in your code; need full message and mark line where error occurs

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo : Updated the error message

Comment: @Schollii: Marked, check please?

Comment: @EtanReisner : Yes, that's right,I am getting an error there, but what shall I have there instead?

Comment: What does `Timer.delayedCall` return?

Answer (score 1):

The `index nil` error means that on that line you are probably getting `nil` as a return value from `LooserText:getParent()`.

Why you would be getting `nil` for that I can't tell you other than presumably because it doesn't have one.

Comment: I suppose,It should work with stage:removeChild(LooserText) but apparently it didn't.If I added the text to stage, then I certainly should be able to remove it from there and in that case, it says it should be a child of stage if I want to be able to remove it from there, any idea?

Comment: What didn't work about `stage:removeChild(LooserText)`? I don't know anything about gideros but I would also assume that should work.

Comment: Apparently, it did not. The error message said that LooserText should be a child of stage, If I added it to stage, it definitely is a child of that did not work at all.

Comment: Are you doing anything else with `LooserText` somewhere else in the code?

Comment: If you check the number of children the stage has before you call `stage:addChild(LooserText)` and again after that does it change?

Comment: Since the text was rendered on the screen so there is no doubt, it definitely was added to stage, other wise text won't be rendered

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, as such. We are trying to figure out why removing it would not work so we need to check assumptions like this one.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation indicates that there is no error condition for `Stage.addChild` except that the object added must be a Sprite. `TextField` inherits Sprite so there is no apparent reason for you to get this error. However, you should not re-assign the return value of `delayedCall` to a global variable of same name as the `Timer` class, this could affect other parts of the application. Since you don't use the returned `Timer` instance, I have removed the assignment. Also, if the `stage:addChild` succeeded then the `removing` can use  `stage`. One thing that is strange is that your `onEnter` just defines `youLose()` but does not call it or return it, is this part of code you ommitted? In any case, you need to add some sanity checks to verify that what you think is happening is really happening w/r/t child add/remove:

```
function onEnter()
    function youLoose()
        local font2 = TTFont.new("billo.ttf", 20,   "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
        LoserText = TextField.new(font2, "You Lose   , Try AGAIN?")
        LoserText:setPosition(100, 100)
        print('Stage num children:' .. stage:getNumChildren())
        stage:addChild(LoserText)
        print('Stage num children:' .. stage:getNumChildren())
        print('LoserText is stage child #' .. stage:getChildIndex(LoserText))
        Timer.delayedCall(1000, removing)
     end 
end

function removing()
    print('Stage num children:' .. stage:getNumChildren())
    print('LoserText is stage child #' .. stage:getChildIndex(LoserText))
    stage:removeChild(LoserText)
    print('Stage num children:' .. stage:getNumChildren())
end
```